# how to let tableRow flash even if it is not visible? (JavaFx)

Tags: java, animation, javafx, tableview

At first my question is how to let a newly added row flash in JavaFx, then I went through a lot of questions related to this topic (such as [javafx: table row flashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164454/javafx-table-row-flashing)). Most of them are using **setRowFactory** and ***override*** the **updateItem** method by adding a Timeline animation which change the state of pseudoClass of the row.
Below is my code, I am trying to building a FlashControl which can be reused.

```
public class TableFlashControl<T> {

    private PseudoClass flashHighlight = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("flash-highlight");
    private List<T> newAdded = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean isFilterApplied = false;
    private boolean isSorted = false;

    public void setIsFilterApplied(boolean isFilterApplied) {
        this.isFilterApplied = isFilterApplied;
    }

    public void add(TableView<T> table){
        ListChangeListener<T> change = c -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    List<? extends T> added = c.getAddedSubList();
                    T lastAdded = added.get(0);
                    if (!isFilterApplied) {
                        newAdded.add(lastAdded);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        table.getItems().addListener(change);
        table.setRowFactory(param -> new TableRow<T>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    return;
                }
                if (newAdded.contains(item)) {
                    if (isSorted) {
                        new Thread(()->{
                            Timeline flasher = new Timeline(
                                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.4), e -> pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, true)),
                                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.8), e -> pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false))
                            );
                            flasher.setCycleCount(2);
                            flasher.play();
                        }).start();
                        if (item == newAdded.get(0)) {
                            newAdded.clear();
                            isSorted = false;
                        }

                    }else{
                        if(item == newAdded.get(0)){
                            isSorted = true;
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here **ListChangeListener** is associated with **table.getItems()** which helps me to record the newly inserted row.

It is possible to add multiple rows within one operation which means **newAdded.size() can be larger than 1**. What's more, rows are inserted from the **top** of the tableView(because I sort it with the **Number**.)

In tableView, not all rows are visible and **updateItem** methods only update those visible rows. My problem comes when these two situations happen(see below).

**The first scenario**

[image: The first scenario]

In first scenario, only 4 rows are visible, if user inserts 5 rows within one time, I cannot record the last row update(the **updateItem** won't be called for the **new_row_5**). Thereby, I cannot clear **newAdded** list (by doing **newAdded.clear()**)

**The second scenario**

[image: The second scenario]

In the second scenario, only 4 rows are visible again. However, there are invisible rows both at top and bottom of the visible rows. If user inserts 2 rows, **one will be visible and the other will be invisible**. In my case, **new_row_2** will flash while **new_row_1** remains invisible. If user scrolls up the tableView when new_row_2 is flashing, he will see **new_row_2** is *flashing* while **new_row_1** is *not* which is really weird.

I also want to know if there is any way to find the number of visible rows.

I am still new to JavaFx and I don't know if this method is good or not. I hope someone can help me fix my problems. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Slightly OT, but why are you wrapping the `Timeline` in a thread? The new thread will simply start the timeline and exit immediately. You can do this perfectly well on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: @James_D Sorry, that was my fault...I should remove the new thread..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach doesn't seem like a clean way to do this. The animation depends on the `TableRow` the item is positioned in and does not seem to support multiple animations happening at the same time. Furthermore it relies on the `equals` method of the item class not being overridden and on the user not adding a item multiple times to the `TableView`. Also you potentially create a large number of `Timeline`s (not necessary to start them from a seperate thread btw, since `Timeline.play()` does not block).

It's better to make the animation depend on the indices. Also keeping track of the `TableRow`s created allows you to access existing cells, should they be be assigned a index that needs to be animated. Also you could handle the animations using a single `AnimationTimer` by storing the data in a suitable data structure.

Also it would IMHO be most convenient to use the `rowFactory` class to implement this logic.

The following example makes the rows flash whether they are on-screen or not.

```
public class FlashTableRowFactory<T> implements Callback<TableView<T>, TableRow<T>> {

    private final static PseudoClass FLASH_HIGHLIGHT = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("flash-highlight");

    public FlashTableRowFactory(TableView<T> tableView) {
        tableView.getItems().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends T> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasPermutated()) {
                    int from = c.getFrom();
                    int to = c.getTo();
                    permutationUpdate(scheduledTasks, c, from, to);
                    permutationUpdate(unscheduledTasks, c, from, to);
                }
                if (c.wasReplaced()) {
                    addRange(c.getFrom(), c.getTo());
                } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    int from = c.getFrom();
                    int removed = c.getRemovedSize();
                    removeRange(scheduledTasks, from, from + removed);
                    removeRange(unscheduledTasks, from, from + removed);
                    modifyIndices(unscheduledTasks, from, -removed);
                    modifyIndices(scheduledTasks, from, -removed);
                } else if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    int from = c.getFrom();
                    int to = c.getTo();
                    modifyIndices(unscheduledTasks, from, to - from);
                    modifyIndices(scheduledTasks, from, to - from);
                    addRange(from, to);
                }
            }

            // remove all flashTasks that are older than the youngest for a
            // given index
            Set<Integer> indices = new HashSet<>();
            removeDuplicates(unscheduledTasks, indices);
            removeDuplicates(scheduledTasks, indices);

            flashingIndices.clear();
            updateFlash(lastUpdate);
            refreshFlash();
            if (!unscheduledTasks.isEmpty()) {
                flasher.start();
            }
        });
        this.tableView = tableView;
    }

    private static void removeDuplicates(List<FlashTask> list, Set<Integer> found) {
        for (Iterator<FlashTask> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            FlashTask next = iterator.next();
            if (!found.add(next.index)) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void modifyIndices(List<FlashTask> list, int minModify, int by) {
        for (FlashTask task : list) {
            if (task.index >= minModify) {
                task.index += by;
            }
        }
    }

    private void addRange(int index, int to) {
        for (; index < to; index++) {
            unscheduledTasks.add(new FlashTask(index));
        }
    }

    private static void removeRange(List<FlashTask> list, int from, int to) {
        for (Iterator<FlashTask> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            FlashTask next = iterator.next();
            if (next.index >= from && next.index < to) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void permutationUpdate(List<FlashTask> list, ListChangeListener.Change<?> c, int from, int to) {
        for (FlashTask task : list) {
            if (task.index < to && task.index >= from) {
                task.index = c.getPermutation(task.index);
            }
        }
    }

    // set of item indices that should flash
    private final Set<Integer> flashingIndices = new HashSet<>();

    // references to every row created by this factory
    private final List<SoftReference<TableRow<T>>> rows = new LinkedList<>();

    // tasks waiting to be scheduled
    private final List<FlashTask> unscheduledTasks = new LinkedList<>();

    // tasks currently being animated
    private final List<FlashTask> scheduledTasks = new LinkedList<>();

    private static class FlashTask {

        int index;
        long schedulingTime;

        public FlashTask(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

    }

    private final TableView<T> tableView;
    private long lastUpdate;

    /**
     * Updates flashingIndices set
     * @param now the current timestamp
     * @return true if the set has been modified, otherwise false.
     */
    private boolean updateFlash(long now) {
        boolean modified = false;
        for (Iterator<FlashTask> iterator = scheduledTasks.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            FlashTask next = iterator.next();

            // running time in seconds
            double runningTime = (now - next.schedulingTime) / (1000d * 1000d * 1000d);

            // slows down the animation for demonstration
            final double animationSpeed = 0.1;

            if (runningTime < 0.4 / animationSpeed) {
                // no need to handle tasks that run for less than 0.4 seconds
                break;
            } else if (runningTime > 1.6 / animationSpeed) {
                // end of task reached
                iterator.remove();
                modified |= flashingIndices.remove(next.index);
            } else if (runningTime > 0.8 / animationSpeed && runningTime < 1.2 / animationSpeed) {
                // second "inactive" interval during animation
                modified |= flashingIndices.remove(next.index);
            } else {
                // activate otherwise
                modified |= flashingIndices.add(next.index);
            }
        }
        return modified;
    }

    private final AnimationTimer flasher = new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            lastUpdate = now;

            // activate waiting flash tasks
            for (FlashTask task : unscheduledTasks) {
                task.schedulingTime = now;
            }
            scheduledTasks.addAll(unscheduledTasks);
            unscheduledTasks.clear();

            if (updateFlash(now)) {
                refreshFlash();
                if (scheduledTasks.isEmpty()) {
                    // stop, if there are no more tasks
                    stop();
                }
            }
        }

    };

    /**
     * Sets the pseudoclasses of rows based on flashingIndices set
     */
    private void refreshFlash() {
        for (Iterator<SoftReference<TableRow<T>>> iterator = rows.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            SoftReference<TableRow<T>> next = iterator.next();
            TableRow<T> row = next.get();
            if (row == null) {
                // remove references claimed by garbage collection
                iterator.remove();
            } else {
                row.pseudoClassStateChanged(FLASH_HIGHLIGHT, flashingIndices.contains(row.getIndex()));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TableRow<T> call(TableView<T> param) {
        if (tableView != param) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This factory can only be used with the table passed to the constructor");
        }
        return new FlashRow();
    }

    private class FlashRow extends TableRow<T> {

        {
            rows.add(new SoftReference<>(this));
        }

        @Override
        public void updateIndex(int i) {
            super.updateIndex(i);

            // update pseudoclass based on flashingIndices set
            pseudoClassStateChanged(FLASH_HIGHLIGHT, flashingIndices.contains(i));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving time to answer my question. This method works perfectly:D. It takes time to understand how it works but I really learn a lot. Thanks again! @fabian